# Magento 2 Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed

Tags: magento2, theme-fallback

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed
#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Fallback/Rule/Theme.php(69): Magento\Framework\View\Design\Fallback\Rule\Simple->getPatternDirs(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/FileResolution/Fallback/Resolver/Simple.php(123): Magento\Framework\View\Design\Fallback\Rule\Theme->getPatternDirs(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/FileResolution/Fallback/Resolver/Simple.php(66): Magento\Framework\View\Design\FileResolution\Fallback\Resolver\Simple->resolveFile(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Design\Fallback\Rule\Theme), 'i18n/en_US.csv', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/FileResolution/Fallback/LocaleFile.php(42): Magento\Framework\View\Design\FileResolution\Fallback\Resolver\Simple->resolve('locale', 'i18n/en_US.csv', 'frontend', Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Theme), 'en_US', NULL)
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/FileSystem.php(105): Magento\Framework\View\Design\FileResolution\Fallback\LocaleFile->getFile('frontend', Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Theme), 'en_US', 'i18n/en_US.csv')
#5 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Translate.php(366): Magento\Framework\View\FileSystem->getLocaleFileName('i18n/en_US.csv', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Translate.php(311): Magento\Framework\Translate->_getThemeTranslationFile('en_US')
#7 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Translate.php(180): Magento\Framework\Translate->_loadThemeTranslation()
#8 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Area.php(240): Magento\Framework\Translate->loadData(NULL, false)
#9 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Area.php(211): Magento\Framework\App\Area->_initTranslate()
#10 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Area.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\Area->_loadPart('translate')
#11 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/DesignLoader.php(55): Magento\Framework\App\Area->load('translate')
#12 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/Design.php(48): Magento\Framework\View\DesignLoader->load()
#13 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(52): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\Design->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Cms\\Con...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'customer-app-ac...')
#15 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Cms\\Con...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'contextPlugin')
#18 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php(106): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Cms\\Con...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCheck')
#21 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/StoreCheck.php(44): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Cms\\Con...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'tax-app-action-...')
#24 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(91): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Cms\\Con...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'weee-app-action...')
#27 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-weee/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(112): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /var/www/html/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#30 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#33 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#34 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#37 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#40 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(68): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#43 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#45 /var/www/html/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#46 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#47 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#48 /var/www/html/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#49 {main}
```

Tried the following answers

1. ["Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100011/required-parameter-theme-dir-was-not-passed)
2. [Magento2.1.0 showing error Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed while saving product in admin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125435/magento2-1-0-showing-error-required-parameter-theme-dir-was-not-passed-while-s)
3. [how to delete a theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100164/how-to-delete-a-theme)

But nothing is working.

Comment: Did you try this one: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/128333/39607?

Comment: you must need `registration.php` and `theme.xml` in your theme for available theme, and after that you add your theme from admin.

Comment: for remove theme pleas run this command in terminal `php bin/magento theme:uninstall area/vendor/name`

Comment: Kaushal, I tried that link as well but it is not working for me.